# Is there a way to add time zone after rendering a time using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, time, filter, datetime-format, time-format

I'm trying to format a date/time in angular to render a timezone maybe as part of the filter. Currently I get back 1552317099640 which renders as 09:11 AM. Is there a prebuilt filter I can use that will just add the time zone to the end of the time? For example... 09:11 AM CST or 09:11 AM (CST). Currently I use:

```
<div>{{ data | timezoneDate:"hh:mm a"}}</div>
```

Comment: The filter provides a timezone offset with `"hh:mm a Z"`, but it displays the offset in hours, not the name of the timezone. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: `timezoneDate` is not a core AngularJS filter. Is it a custom filter that you wrote?